# How can I solve iOS Team Provisioning Profile warning

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

There are some similar question posted on here but they does not solve my issue.

I am Learning Swift with Xcode 7. I have developed an app which I have deployed on my iPhone 4s, I was getting warning in Xcode after deployment.

> The provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: " is expiring
>   soon

However, App was working fine but after few days I stopped working and I had to connect to Xcode and deploy app again. The app is working again. However, I see the warning sign again as below.

[image]

I have done research and found out I can resolve this issue from Apple Developers account. However I do not have developer's account as it cost $99 a year. Is Apple developer subscription is necessory ? in order to solve this issue permenently ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a free developer account, the provisionning profile is just usable about a week. You *have* to built your app again periodically to be able to use it!
It's Apple's rules...

Answer (score 1):

If you submit app to appstore or beta-distribution (Hockeyapp, ...), you must renew developer account.

If you only wanna run app on your device, from iOS9, you can do it without developer accout
http://www.wastedpotential.com/running-xcode-projects-on-a-device-without-a-developer-account-in-xcode-7/

Comment: I know that I can deploy app on device without developer's account which already I have done couple of time. But I always get warning as mentioned in my question. I would be appreciate if you can help me to resolve that warning permanently

Comment: Your current provisioning is free/testing only ?

Comment: I have all the setting as described in your link still no help to resolve warning. I think there is no way we can solve that warning and we have to built provisioning profile every week . Thank you for answer though, I have voted up.